# SQL Query, error returning more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I input the following:

```
SELECT
    APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM,
    APPL_START_TERM,
    APPL_APPLICANT,
    STC_TERM,
    STC_PERSON_ID
FROM 
    ODS_APPLICATIONS
JOIN 
    SPT_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED ON STC_PERSON_ID = APPL_APPLICANT
WHERE
    APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM = (
        SELECT 
            (APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM) 
        FROM ODS_APPLICATIONS
        WHERE APPL_START_TERM LIKE STC_TERM + '%'
        AND APPL_APPLICANT = STC_PERSON_ID
)
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I understand that this is related to my nested query pulling more than one row which SQL seems to disagree with, any ideas to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Use `IN` or `= ANY`.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator only allows you to compare against a single value. Your query is returning more than one value. You can either change your query to only return one value, or change your operator.

The `in` operator will return true if the value matches any of the returned values.

You could also modify the  `=` operator with the `all` operator. If you select with `= all` the expression return true if the value matches all of the values returned.

Which solution you use is entirely dependent on what you want to achieve. My guess is you want `in`.

---

```
SELECT
APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM,
APPL_START_TERM,
APPL_APPLICANT,
STC_TERM,
STC_PERSON_ID

FROM ODS_APPLICATIONS
JOIN SPT_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED ON STC_PERSON_ID = APPL_APPLICANT

WHERE
APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM in (SELECT (APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM) FROM ODS_APPLICATIONS
WHERE APPL_START_TERM LIKE STC_TERM + '%'
AND APPL_APPLICANT = STC_PERSON_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're only wanting the first result for the sub query, it should read `select top 1` not `select`.

If you're wanting the sub query to return more than 1 result, and your main query to sift through more than one result, you can replace `=` to `in` , and the sub query won't need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting it as an EXISTS...

```
FROM 
    ODS_APPLICATIONS oa
    JOIN SPT_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED ssad
        ON oa.STC_PERSON_ID = ssad.APPL_APPLICANT
WHERE
    EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM 
                ODS_APPLICATIONS oa2 
            WHERE 
                oa.APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM = oa2.APPL_ACAD_PROGRAM
                AND APPL_START_TERM LIKE STC_TERM + '%'
                AND APPL_APPLICANT = STC_PERSON_ID
                );
```

Comment: Using an exists statement would add a lot of unnecessary overhead to the query.

Comment: Not sure who told you that but they were lying to you. The EXISTS method tends to be far more efficient than an IN or JOIN in this situation... and when it's not, it's as efficient...